# How do i download multiple images on android from localhost server?

Tags: java, android

I created an android application to download images from my local server, but i failed to do it. I tried few times but i did not work out. Here is my source code at the exact class i created to do the function i want:

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray =  new ArrayList<Bitmap>(4);
public static  final String URL = "http://localhost/img/";
Button load_img;
ImageView imageview;
Bitmap bitmap;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_monitor);

    load_img = (Button)findViewById(R.id.load);
    imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    load_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new LoadImage().execute(new String[]{URL});
            //img.setImageBitmap(bitmapArray.ge);
        }
    });
}

private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Monitor.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Fetching Images ....");
        pDialog.show();

    }
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            bitmap = null;
            for(String url : urls){
                bitmap = downloadImage(url);
            }

            //List<Bitmap> bitmap = new ArrayList<Bitmap>;
           // bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(args[0]).getContent());
        return bitmap;
    }


    private Bitmap downloadImage(String arg0){

        bitmap = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

        try{
            stream = getHttpConnection(arg0);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null,bmOptions);
            stream.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bitmapArray.add(bitmap);
        return  bitmap;
    }



    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        if(result != null){
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }else{
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(Monitor.this,"Failed in downloading the image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    //creating open connection
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException{
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if(httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you getting an error? Please explain what is happening.

Comment: `localhost` is not accessible from either emulator or the physical device. If you are testing on emulator, and your server is also on the same machine, use `10.0.2.2.2` and if your server is running on another machine, use the IP of that machine. If you are testing on a physical device, use the IP of the server machine.

Comment: you are passing one url and want to get list in onBackground

Comment: But i could access the localhost using its IP where i am also at the same machine. But i can not load multiple images with my code, so i tried the above codes, but it still doesnt work, also i changed the IP as what you said earlier [10.0.2.2.2] and it still nothing happened.

Comment: 1- LOCALHOST IS NOT VALID, USE IP OF PC THAT RUNS THE SERVER, **EX** 192.168.1.2...... 2- WHAT ERROR ARE YOU GETTING? POST IT